# Java 3d programming - Unable to access the changed position of 3d object

Tags: java, image-processing, java-3d

We are working on a augmented reality project wherein the user will be able to virtually place 3d furniture objects on camera.

We are able to place the 3d object (obj file) on capture image, java 3d allows me dynamically change or re-position the object  using mouse and ViewingPlatform class, but I am not able to detect the new position of the object.

Can you tell me on how to detect the Changed Angle or position of the 3d object?

```
public BranchGroup createSceneGraph(String file) {
    objScale = new TransformGroup();
    objTrans = new TransformGroup();
    trans = new Transform3D();
    BranchGroup objRoot = new BranchGroup();
    Transform3D t3d = new Transform3D();
    t3d.setScale(scaling);
    trans.setTranslation(new Vector3f(xloc, yloc, 0.0f));
    objScale.setTransform(trans);
    objRoot.addChild(objScale);
    objTrans.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
    objTrans.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);
    objTrans.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_EXTEND);
    objTrans.setCapability(Group.ALLOW_CHILDREN_EXTEND);
    objTrans.setCapability(Group.ALLOW_CHILDREN_WRITE);
    objTrans.setCapability(Group.ALLOW_BOUNDS_WRITE);
    objTrans.setCapability(Group.ALLOW_BOUNDS_READ);
    objScale.addChild(objTrans);
    int flags = ObjectFile.RESIZE;
    flags |= ObjectFile.TRIANGULATE;
    flags |= ObjectFile.STRIPIFY;
    ObjectFile f = new ObjectFile(flags,
            (float) (creaseAngle * Math.PI / 180.0));
    System.out.println(60 * Math.PI / 180.0);
    try {
        loadscente = f.load(filename);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    objTrans.addChild(loadscente.getSceneGroup());
    bounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 50.0);
    System.out.println(bounds + "Bounds");
    getBackgroundImage();
    objRoot.addChild(bgNode);
    addLightsToUniverse();
    return objRoot;
}
 public void addCompInPanel() {
    GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
    c = new Canvas3D(config);
    jPanel2.add("Center", c);
    c.addKeyListener(this);
    c.addMouseListener(this);
    // Create a simple scene and attach it to the virtual universe
    BranchGroup scene = createSceneGraph(filename);
    u = new SimpleUniverse(c);
    // add mouse behaviors to the ViewingPlatform
    ViewingPlatform viewingPlatform = u.getViewingPlatform();
    PlatformGeometry pg = new PlatformGeometry();
    // Set up the ambient light
    Color3f ambientColor = new Color3f(Color.RED);
    AmbientLight ambientLightNode = new AmbientLight(ambientColor);
    ambientLightNode.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
    pg.addChild(ambientLightNode);
    // Set up the directional lights
    Color3f light1Color = new Color3f(Color.RED);
    Vector3f light1Direction = new Vector3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    Color3f light2Color = new Color3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    Vector3f light2Direction = new Vector3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    DirectionalLight light1 = new DirectionalLight(light1Color,
            light1Direction);
    light1.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
    pg.addChild(light1);
    DirectionalLight light2 = new DirectionalLight(light2Color,
            light2Direction);
    light2.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
    pg.addChild(light2);
    viewingPlatform.setPlatformGeometry(pg);

    keyNavBeh = new KeyNavigatorBehavior(objTrans);
    keyNavBeh.setSchedulingBounds(new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(),
            1000.0));
    System.out.println(keyNavBeh.getSchedulingBounds() + " keyNavBeh.getSchedulingBounds();");
    objTrans.addChild(keyNavBeh);

    // This will move the ViewPlatform back a bit so the
    // objects in the scene can be viewed.
    viewingPlatform.setNominalViewingTransform();
    OrbitBehavior orbit = new OrbitBehavior(c, OrbitBehavior.REVERSE_ALL);
    orbit.setSchedulingBounds(bounds);
    viewingPlatform.setViewPlatformBehavior(orbit);
    u.addBranchGraph(scene);
    jSlider1StateChanged(null);
}
```

Comment: Show us the code which you use to display and move the object.

Comment: I have posted the code ...   setPlatformgeomerty is used to set the geometry and automatic rotation of mouse

Comment: `objTrans.getTransform()` should return the transformation matrix which should change when you move around using the keyboard. Is that correct?

Comment: objTrans.getTransform() not return matrix

Comment: The code for `KeyNavigator` uses `targetTG.setTransform(vpTrans);` so it better does.

Comment: See http://sourcecodebrowser.com/java3d/1.5.2plus-pdfsg/classcom_1_1sun_1_1j3d_1_1utils_1_1behaviors_1_1keyboard_1_1_key_navigator.html#a4603d261e9c14bea71789f3f3753c15e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code for `KeyNavigator`, the code in the method `integrateTransformChanges()` updates the transform group:

```
targetTG.setTransform(vpTrans);
```

Note that this changes the transform matrix applied to the group, it doesn't change object vertices or the object's origin as such - when the while scene is rendered, the transformation matrix is applied to every vector.

So a simple `objTrans.getTransform()` will do the trick.

**[EDIT]** To get the transformations done by the `OrbitBehavior`, use `viewingPlatform.getViewPlatformTransform().getTransform()`

See https://github.com/hharrison/java3d-utils/blob/1f025a8787edec6e2ae1eab3a3fd0eb59319e3c4/src/classes/share/com/sun/j3d/utils/behaviors/vp/ViewPlatformBehavior.java

Related:

- Source code: https://github.com/hharrison/java3d-utils/blob/master/src/classes/share/com/sun/j3d/utils/behaviors/keyboard/KeyNavigator.java
- http://sourcecodebrowser.com/java3d/1.5.2plus-pdfsg/classcom_1_1sun_1_1j3d_1_1utils_1_1behaviors_1_1keyboard_1_1_key_navigator.html#a4603d261e9c14bea71789f3f3753c15e

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Is there any workaround for mouse?

Comment: When I use key-navigator,we are able to fetch the new X Y & Z co-ordinates of the object but the angle is still missing.         In order to rotate the object using keys, we are selecting one of the side of the object using mouse and then rotating using keys. Can you suggest on how to get that angle or a way to update co-ordinates when the object is moved using mouse?

Comment: @AaronDigulla Please update your link as yours points to an obsolete version of Java 3D. The source code of this class is here (Java 3D 1.6.0): https://github.com/hharrison/java3d-utils/blob/master/src/classes/share/com/sun/j3d/utils/behaviors/keyboard/KeyNavigator.java I don't want to downvote your answer because of that.

Comment: Rotation should happen when you use `Alt+Arrow-keys`. But my guess is in your code, the rotation happens via `OrbitBehavior`, which is connected only to the canvas, so you probably need to look at the global transformation set in the canvas (probably via `getViewPlatformTransform()` object).

Comment: @gouessej: Thanks, I misseed that one :-)

Comment: @TechnoWingsInc-Rajesh: I've added links to the source of `ViewPlatformBehavior` which is used by `OrbitBehavior` plus how to get that transformation matrix.